# flutter google immutable list

Tags: firebase-authentication, flutter

I'm signing in a user with email and password with firebase auth for flutter and after i create a user. I keep getting an error that says:

```
"Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.chat5-5I0dEKw0n-K2p_N3OZOtzQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.chat5-5I0dEKw0n-K2p_N3OZOtzQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.chat5-5I0dEKw0n-K2p_N3OZOtzQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]"
```

and my app crashes, any help is much appreciated,
thank you.

im guessing i need to add a dependency for immutable lists but not sure what/which

Comment: That's not enough information. What steps allow to reproduce?

Answer (score 0):

found the depedency is  "compile(group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '18.0')" put in the app level gradle

thank you